# Send email after 7 hours from the due date field

Tags: visual-workflow, tasks, email-alert

I have a requirement which is to send an email alert to the task owner when it is due.
But this email needs to be sent at a specific time.

In the flow builder, I've already tried using the scheduled path but it doesn't allow me to determine a time. It also does not read times defined via formula.

I didn't find any forum or similar documentation, as it is a date field and not date/time.

I can't use code. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Hello Mag, I think this trailhead will shows how to use date field in `Scheduled path` flow. Trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/record-triggered-flows/add-a-scheduled-task-to-your-flow. So can you please help to add some snapshot to understand your issue clearly?

Comment: Hi Mohanraj Sivalingam,

I've already tried using the Scheduled path.
But the task object's due date field is of type Date, it seems that it doesn't work when I schedule it for 7 hours after the due date. It doesn't send any emails. But if I enter 1 day after the due date it sends the alert at 00:00, I need it to be at 07:00 AM.

Comment: I configured the flow to start when a task is created or updated.

Respecting the following conditions:

{!$Record.ActivityDate} < TODAY() && ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status}, "Open")

Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SFDC, [Record Triggered flow](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/what-is-a-record-triggered-flow#:%7E:text=A%20record%2Dtriggered%20flow%20allows,is%20created%20and%2For%20updated.) having a function `Scheduled Path`, Which will help to **send an email** into Task owner on `7 Hours After` only from the `Due Date` received time for that task. Not a specific time like Morning 7AM or Evening 5AM as constant.

For ex: If the Task record ***'X'*** will got the `Due Date` value as Oct 7th, 2023 12:00:00 IST means which schedule a email action to send the email on Oct 7th, 2023 19:00:00 IST.

If you're want to send an email about the Task's `Due date` pending on Every Morning 7 AM for that specific date/Including the previous date, Please create a report on Task object and ask the users to [subscribe](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_subscribe_lex.htm&type=5) that report from his end. So that report results are send an email into that owner every morning 7 AM.

Hope it helps.